# Show Product on Base of Selected product Category

Tags: odoo-12

how to list products in sale order respective to selected product categories
I want to add product category option in sale order line odoo 12 on the base of product category only those products will be shown in product list which lies b/w selected product category. please help me with this.

Comment: Can anyone can help me this one

Comment: Do you need to filter products by category?